# What are all commands for npx create-*?

Tags: node.js, npx

I know npx create-react-app and npx-next-app what are all others app npx support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) is a program that downloads any package on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). `create-react-app` isn't a *command for npx*, rather, you're telling npx:

1. Download [`react-create-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app)
2. Cache it (but not in the current directory, so it will stay 'clean')
3. Try to run it as a program (the [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/a422bf227cf5294a34d68696664e9568a152fd8f/packages/create-react-app/package.json#L25) file says how to do that, in this case: "run `node ./index.js`")

`npx` knows nothing of React or Next.js and it doesn't have these things built in. All it knows is about is npm and how to run any (executable) package it downloads from there, like `npx gulp` or `npx serve`.

If you're working with a new framework and you're wondering if there's a utility to quickly set up a project, [just search NPM and see what pops up](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=create-app).

Answer (score 1):

There is no set list because `npx` is [a package runner for Node.js](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner). Running `npx create-react-app` will try to find the package `create-react-app` and run it. The package will be downloaded if not locally installed.

Therefore, the list of supported commands for `npx` is "everything included in the repositories used by NPM". You can even create your own package, not visible to anybody else, and run it with `npx`.